# vQmod for OpenCart 2 install instructions

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, vqmod

I am using OpenCart 2.0.3.1 and I've followed the installation instructions for vQmod located here.

[vQmod for OpenCart 2](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19501)

Then I followed the instructions to upload an XML file but I am not seeing any changes.  Do I need to also install this vQmod?

[Github vQmod](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod)

This is what my XML file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
<id>Admin modifications</id>
<version>1.0</version>
<vqmver>2.5.1</vqmver>
<author>Me</author>
<file path="my-dashboard/language/english/" name="english.php">
    <operation info="Change short date format">
        <search position="replace">
            <![CDATA[
                $_['date_format_short']             = 'd/m/Y';
            ]]>
        </search>
        <add>
            <![CDATA[
                $_['date_format_short']             = 'm/d/Y';
            ]]>
        </add>
    </operation>
</file>
</modification>
```

I used the extension installer to upload the XML file in OpenCart and then used the refresh button in Extensions -> Modifications yet my date format is not updating in the admin interface.

The problem could be that I need to install vQmod from the Github link above but if so why isn't that in the install instructions on the OpenCart extensions page.

**UPDATE 09/01/2015 - RESOLVED**

I have resolved the issue.  If you change your admin folder like I did to my-dashboard, in the vQmod XML file you shouldn't use the new folder name but still use admin.  All is working now.  Probably should add that to the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. If you change your admin folder like I did to my-dashboard, in the vQmod XML file you shouldn't use the new folder name but still use admin. All is working now. Probably should add that to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [instructions](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19501) that you followed aren't enough explicit, but you have to install vQmod to run any modification. See 
[*How to install vQmod on OpenCart*](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/Installing-vQmod-on-OpenCart) on the wiki to complete your installation.

Comment: Well there is a comment from the author on the OpenCart extension page that disagrees with what you wrote.  Read below, so i don't think your suggestion is correct.

@danieldd: First of all, it looks like you are using the external VQmod from https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki, in which case you shouldn't also use the one from here, namely, http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19501. You can have only one VQmod installed on your OpenCart server.

Comment: If the author of the extension specifies that you shouldn't install the external version of vQmod, my answer is actually inadequate (and I probably should delete it). By the way, you should perhaps also edit your question, since installing vQmod externally can't seem to solve your issue.

Comment: Well I am sure installing vQmod from the Github repository will work but this one is supposed to be better in some regards and this guy is actively supporting it when OpenCart is updated.  So that is why I wanted to use it.  It has so many downloads it should just work.  Hopefully someone will chime in with some advice.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: I see that you've solved your problem, but maybe [this issue](https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/issues/56) and [this thread](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=131&t=151298) could be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to any type of installation required for this module just upload this module in root directory 
It Will replace two files

1 admin\controller\extension\installer.php

2 admin\controller\extension\modification.php

After that it will work fine.

Here is an example of my working xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<modification>
  <id>Carousel_featured</id>    
  <version>1.0.1</version>
  <vqmver>2.5.0</vqmver>
  <author>Hardik kotak</author>

<file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/module/featured.tpl"> 
  <operation>           
   <search position="top"><![CDATA[]]></search>
      <add><![CDATA[<div class="featured-product product-listing">]]></add>
    </operation>
</file>
</modification>
```

**My xml get works after name change my_modification.xml to my_modification.vqmod.xml**

**I have placed this file in root/vqmod/xml/my_modification.vqmod.xml**

Comment: I have done all the steps you outlined.  It does not work for me.  I was using the Extension Installer in OpenCart but tried placing the vqmod.xml file in vqmod/xml and that doesn't work either.  Even after going to the Extension Installer in OpenCart and hitting the refresh button.  I suspect being that I am changing an admin file and my admin path is my-dashboard opposed to admin that this could be the problem.  But why isn't that documented if so.  Also when I do use Extension Installer in OpenCart I do see the XML file being added to the modification table in SQL.

Comment: I figured it out, see my answer and uptick if you can so it helps others. This obviously should be documented on the OpenCart extension listing.  I will ping the author.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that you can only use one VQmod system on your Opencart.

So it's either the one from https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki, or the one from http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=19501. Do not install both of them, otherwise your VQmod XML files get processed twice!